# How to get available free space for a partition on MacOS (sierra-catalina)

Tags: c++, macos, disk

Trying to get per-partition available disk space, I found many solutions online, all of them unfortunately don't work.

The question is: How to programmatically get available (free) space for a given partition?

What I tried:

```
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path diskPath("/dev/disk0s1");
    size_t space = std::filesystem::space(diskPath).available;
    std::cout << "Free space for disk01: " << space << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compilation error:

`'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15`
`'path' has been explicitly marked unavailable here`

I know there is a similar library in `boost`, but I would like to avoid boost if possible.

(Targeting 10.12 +)

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
int main() 
{
    struct statvfs buf;

    if (!statvfs("/dev/disk0s1", &buf)) 
    {
        size_t space = buf.f_bfree*buf.f_bsize;
        std::cout << "Free space for disk01: " << space << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
      std::cerr << "Error here" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this retrieve `0`for all partitions. Note: some values like `f_bsize`are filled correctly, but `f_bfree`is always `0`.

Answer (score -1):

From [this `std::filesyste::space` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/space):

> Determines the information about the filesystem **on which the pathname p is located**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

That means the path you provide must be to a file or directory on the filesystem itself, not the path to the device file.

For example if `/dev/disk0s1` is mounted as `/home` then you could use that mount path itself (i.e. `std::filesystem::space("/home")`).

Note that [`statvfs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/statvfs.html) works exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for the note. This tell me that even if I could use `std::filesystem`, it would not helps. But how to get available space?

Comment: @AdrianMaire Why wouldn't it help? This works just like the `df` command in any POSIX system: You pass a path to a file on the mounted filesystem (or the mount path itself). Is the problem that you don't have the mount paths?

Comment: Because std::filesystem is not supported.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Ah I see. Then please read the linked `statvfs` reference. You need to give a path to the mounted filesystem, not the device file.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. However, what I have is the device (e.g. `disk0s3`) not a mounted file path. Considering only mounted partitions (I understand that it is unpractical to check available space on unmounted disks), how would you find the mounted path for the given disk?

Comment: @AdrianMaire You could check `/etc/mtab` to find the line containing the device file, and parse out the mount point, which you can then pass on to `statvfs`. There might be other methods on macOS that I don't know about.